# Django not saving data with post

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have this view:

```
class TaskApiView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = TaskSerializer(data=request.data)
        print(request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            print("valid", serializer.data)
            serializer.save()
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            print(serializer.errors)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

request body:

```
{
    "content": "asd"
}
```

log:

```
{'content': 'asd'}
valid {'id': 30}
[21/Oct/2023 11:33:19] "POST /api/task/create HTTP/1.1" 201 0
```

But when I try to get all tasks with this view

```
class TaskListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Task.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
```

I get just the id:

```
[
    {
        "id": 25
    }
]
```

Serializer:

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = "__all__"
```

Model

```
    id: models.UUIDField(unique=True, auto_created=True)
    content: models.CharField(default="")
    creationDate: models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    author: models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status: models.CharField(
        choices=StatusEnum,
        max_length=5,
        default=StatusEnum.TODO,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id + self.content
```

settings.py:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser",
    ]
}
```

I want to create a task with content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that's because your model only has an `id` field. Indeed, you define fields as attributes, not as annotations, so:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(unique=True, auto_created=True)
    content = models.CharField(default='')
    creationDate = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(
        choices=StatusEnum, max_length=5, default=StatusEnum.TODO
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id} {self.content}'
```

You will need to make a migration and migrate to migrate it properly. Likely injecting defaults for already existing models.

With the given data you provide, the serializer will however reject the data: you don't specify a value for the `author`.

Comment: Thank you sir! This was breaking my head